# The Gamma-transform and $p$-adic $L$-functions

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, p-adic-analysis, iwasawa-theory

I'm currently reading the paper "[On the $\mu$-invariant of the $\Gamma$-transform of a rational function](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01388565)" by W Sinnott. In this paper, he gives an alternate proof that $\mu=0$ for abelian number fields. (This was originally proven by Ferrero–Washington.)

In doing so, he defines the Gamma transform of a measure as follows. If $\alpha$ is a $\mathbf{Z}_p$-valued measure on $\mathbf{Z}_p$, then the Gamma transform of $\alpha$ is:

$$\Gamma_{\alpha}(s) = \int_{\mathbf{Z}_p^{\times}} \langle x \rangle^s d \alpha(x).$$

He then shows that the $p$-adic $L$-function attached to a Dirichlet character arises as the Gamma-transform of some measure $\alpha$.

I'd like to have some more background / context about the Gamma-transform.

*My questions are:* What is the motivation for the Gamma-transform, and what problem about $p$-adic $L$-functions was it originally used to solve? Where was it first introduced, and where can I find some more details about how the Gamma-transform was used to construct the Kubota–Leopoldt $p$-adic $L$-function?

I am sensing that Sinnott is calling upon an existing body of knowledge when he uses the Gamma-transform, but I am not sure where to learn how it has been used historically. Any references about it would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Where have you see $p$-adic $L$-functions of Dirichlet characters constructed, if this method is new to you? In Lang's Cyclotomic Fields I & II this is the approach used to build those functions after some $p$-adic measure-theoretic preliminaries.  It resembles the Mellin transform way of expressing the classical Dirichlet $L$-functions (including the Riemann zeta-function) as an integral over $(0,\infty)$ of x^s against a rapidly decaying exponential function. So think of this integral as being a $p$-adic analogue of classical Mellin transform integrals.

Comment: @KConrad Thanks for the comments, I'll read Lang's book to learn more. I've only seen Iwasawa's construction of the p-adic L function via Stickelberger elements, so reading this should be helpful.

Comment: You may want to read Leopoldt's "Eine p-adische Theorie der Zetawerte II" (which is the continuation of Kubota and Leopoldt's original construction of the $p$-adic zeta function). There he explains the construction of his $p$-adic $\Gamma$-transform starting for what he calls the "classical $\Gamma$-transform" which comes from the Mellin transform (as KConrad explains). The $p$-adic $\Gamma$-transform applies to convergent power series, and if I recall correctly, the transform over measures is the same of Leopoldt applied to the power series of the measure (given by the Iwasawa isomorphism).

Comment: pd: I meant read the introduction to Leopoldt's "Eine p-adische Theorie der Zetawerte II. My german is awful so I use DeepL to translate articles in german to english.

Comment: @efs thanks, this intro looks like it could be helpful. (I also appreciate you mentioning DeepL - because I also don't know any German!)

Comment: You can download Leopoldt's article here: https://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PID=GDZPPN002190567